# Comet Server used on Twitter and Facebook

Tags: facebook, twitter, comet

What Comet Server does Twitter and Facebook use?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Chat uses an Erlang-based chat server.  See more here:

- http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=14218138919
- http://www.erlang-factory.com/upload/presentations/31/EugeneLetuchy-ErlangatFacebook.pdf